# arcgis flex api turn on/off group layers

Tags: layers, arcgis-flex-api, flex, group-layer, flash-builder

I just started using ArcGIS API for Flex. In my case I need to provide a widget to turn on and off several layers together, which means these layers need to be turned on together or turned off together. Is it possible to do so? Should sublayer in `operationallayers` cater for it?

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 and ArcGIS API for Flex 3.6.